# how to monitor multiple log files?

Tags: logging

I have to monitor multiple logs. By now I have a iTerm on my mac with several windows. So I have all logs on one sight. The idea is now to have a RaspberryPie with an extra monitor. By now after a reboot I have to rearrange the iTerm windows each time and start tail -f. How can this happen (on the RaspberryPie) by autostart? Is there a viewer which saves windows positions and starts monitoring log files after reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tail` with multiple `-f` parameters to open multiple files at once, like this:

`tail -f /var/log/file1 -f /var/log/file2 -f /var/log/file3`

Alternatively you can use a tool such as [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/features.php) and then set it to start on boot.